# UIScrollView Memory-Allocation and Release

Tags: xcode, memory-management, uiscrollview

I am working on a pretty simple and straightforward app that uses a couple of pages with scroll views. I have an array of images in ViewDidLoad and then a mutable array that shows current page plus and minus 1. There is a purge page method which is supposed to remove the extra images from the superview. When running this on an actual device with a large quantity of images, a memory warning comes up after scrolling through 50 or so images and then the app crashes. I ran this through instruments and see that the memory in increasing substantially with each swipe. When creating the array I used imageNamed as well as imageWithContentsOfFile and either way gives close to the same result. I realize there have been multiple scrollview questions here, but somehow I cannot seem to get past this one. Frustrating to say the least. I hope someone can look at this with a fresh set of eyes and shed some light on my problem. Thanks very much in advance.

EDIT: Forgot to mention ARC use. Yes, I use ARC.

Code: .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

@end
```

and the .m file

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pageImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pageViews;

- (void)loadVisiblePages;
- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page;
- (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page;
@end

@implementation FirstViewController


@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
@synthesize pageControl = _pageControl;

@synthesize pageImages = _pageImages;
@synthesize pageViews = _pageViews;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)loadVisiblePages {
    // First, determine which page is currently visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    NSInteger page = (NSInteger)floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth)     / (pageWidth * 2.0f));

// Update the page control
self.pageControl.currentPage = page;

// Work out which pages you want to load
NSInteger firstPage = page - 1;
NSInteger lastPage = page + 1;

// Purge anything before the first page
for (NSInteger i=0; i<firstPage; i++) {
    [self purgePage:i];
}

// Load pages in our range
for (NSInteger i=firstPage; i<=lastPage; i++) {
    [self loadPage:i];
}

// Purge anything after the last page
for (NSInteger i=lastPage+1; i<self.pageImages.count; i++) {
    [self purgePage:i];
}

}

- (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page {
    if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count) {
    // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
    return;
    }

    // Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
    UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull*)pageView != [NSNull null]) {
        [pageView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:[NSNull null]];


    }

}


- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page {
    if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count) {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return;
    }

    // 1
    UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull*)pageView == [NSNull null]) {
        // 2
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0.0f;

        // 3
        UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:page]];
        newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        newPageView.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];
        // 4
       [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newPageView];

    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Load the pages that are now on screen
    [self loadVisiblePages];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // 1
    self.pageImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD1.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD2.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD3.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD4.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD5.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD6.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD7.jpg"],
                  .....
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD292.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD293.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD294.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD295.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD296.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD297.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD298.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD299.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBD300.jpg"],                       


                       nil];

    NSInteger pageCount = self.pageImages.count;

    // 2
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount;

    // 3
    self.pageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
        [self.pageViews addObject:[NSNull null]];
    } 
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // 4
    CGSize pagesScrollViewSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width *     self.pageImages.count, pagesScrollViewSize.height);

    // 5
    [self loadVisiblePages];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

@end
```

I really appreciate you taking the time to look at this and hope there is someone out there who can point me in the right direction.

THANKS!

Comment: In `// 3` you don't release the created image view.

Answer (score 3):

Loading the actual images into the array incurs a much larger overhead than storing just the names in the array and loading the image like

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:page]];
UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[image release];
```

At this point, only the newPageView will hold a reference to the image in memory, and when that newPageView is removed from it's superview, the image in memory will be released.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you are using ARC or not, but without ARC there are obvious problems in memory management. In `loadPage:` at comment "// 3" you create `newPageView` with a retain count of 1, then add it as a subview of `self.scrollView` and to the array `self.pageViews`. Thus it has an overall retain count of +3. In `purgePage:` you remove it from `self.scrollView` and `self.pageViews` but are still left with an overall retain count of +1. Thus the `UIImageView` for each page is forgotten but not deallocated.

You can fix this by using ARC in your project or modifying the line where you create `newPageView` to be instead:

```
UIImageView *newPageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:page]] autorelease];
```

Comment: I do have this set-up with ARC.

Comment: In that case at a glance I don't see anything wrong. Probably time to pull out the memory tracking tools such as leaks and using heapshot analysis with the Instruments application such as is described in [bbum's article](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/).